# Using Google Freebase API, with the dump?

Tags: java, google-api, freebase, google-api-java-client

I have been trying to understand how to use Freebase, in particular the search tool. I studied many pages, for examples : 
http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2013/02/11/getting-started-with-freebase-api/

Almost all of these pages talk about creating an account OAuth and using the service by sending queries to the api page ( [https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=one%20piece&indent=true&filter=(all%20type:animation)&key=xyz](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=one%20piece&indent=true&filter=%28all%20type%3aanimation%29&key=xyz) ) or sth like that.

On the other hand, I found that there is a dump of Freebase here: 
https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

Q1: By seeing this, this question comes to my mind that, when there is a dump of Freebase available, why should still query from the online API website?

Q2: So, if I want to use the dump, does that mean that I won't need the API anymore? Then, is there any tool for using the dump directly?